# How to "make login" to a mote in COOJA/Contiki?

Tags: contiki

I am very new with COOJA/contiki. I want to do the example "sky-shell", so I try to make some motes. My problem is that I don't know how to access to the mote (with the real device, we can use "make login" command to handle it). I do some search but I got nothing. Any idea?

n.q.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to access to a mote in COOJA simulator.

To do that, you have to click on the mote with the right button, then, in the shortcut menu you click on "Show serial port on Sky 1". Then, you will see a window that shows all data witten by the mote, and it allows you to send data to the mote.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You have just saved my day. Thank you so much!